# !! c operator, is a two NOT?

Tags: c, operators, logical-operators

I reading this [code](https://gist.github.com/909424#L115), and have this line

```
 switch (!!up + !!left) {
```

what is `!!` operator ? two logical NOT ?

Comment: Yup. Sounds like whoever wrote that didn't quite know what they were doing.

Comment: Did you think to, you know, try it and find out?

Comment: @Saucemaster, actually it's an idiom for mapping zero/nonzero to 0/1.  It might also qualify as excessively clever in this particular use case (see "premature optimization").

Comment: @SauceMaster: On the contrary.  The double not trick is used very often.  The Linux kernel source has some uses of it, and I'm pretty sure that the kernel hackers know what they are doing.

Comment: It's the logical-yes operator.

Comment: @geekosaur and C2H50H: Thanks for the info, learn something new every day!

Comment: I see no good reason why they didn't use `switch(up || left)` in this case, which is much more readable IMO? Does anyone else?

Comment: @weston `(up || left)` will yield `0` or `1`, whereas `(!!up + !!left)` will yield `0`, `1`, or `2`.

Comment: **SEE ALSO**: [What is “!!” in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751973/what-is-in-c)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

yes, it's two nots.

`!!a` is `1` if `a` is non-zero and `0` if `a` is `0`

You can think of `!!` as clamping, as it were, to `{0,1}`. I personally find the usage a bad attempt to appear fancy.

Comment: not to be confused with a double knot, which is hard to get out of.

Comment: It's not so much "clamping" as it is "normalizing".

Comment: If you don't like it, what would you prefer? `(_Bool)` (or `(bool)` if `stdbool.h` has been included) works on C99 but it seems gratuitously dependent on C99, and I find a lot fewer people understand how cast-to-bool works than understand the `!!` idiom. The other alternative, `expr?1:0`, is just ugly and gratuitously verbose.

Comment: "a bad attempt to appear fancy" 

Answer (score 15):

You can imagine it like this:

```
!(!(a))
```

If you do it step by step, this make sense

```
result = !42;    //Result = 0
result = !(!42)  //Result = 1 because !0 = 1
```

This will return `1` with any number (-42, 4.2f, etc.) but only with `0`, this will happens

```
result = !0;    //Result = 1
result = !(!0)  //result = 0
```

Answer (score 8):

`!!` is a more-portable (pre-C99) alternative to `(_Bool)`.

Answer (score 4):

You're right.  It's two nots.  To see why one would do this, try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(const int a)
{
    return !!a;
}

int main()
{
    const int b = foo(7);
    printf(
        "The boolean value is %d, "
        "where 1 means true and 0 means false.\n",
        b
    );
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs `The boolean value is 1, where 1 means true and 0 means false.`  If you drop the `!!`, though, it outputs `The boolean value is 7, where 1 means true and 0 means false.`