# Using Logical AND 1 when setting a variable in C

Tags: c

While looking through some code today, I came across an interesting(unecessary?) method for setting a variable:  Adding a logical AND to the value.

```
LED_GRN = (ivLEDGrnSequence & ivLEDSlot) && 1;
```

I looked around a bit more for some of these occurrences and found them throughout the code, but in different forms:

As an argument for a function:

```
isoAgCmdHideShow(iObjectID,( (ecu.l & sVar->mask) && 1), (uint8_t *)TxMsg.buf);
```

In a conditional:

```
if( (usbQueue.selection & USB_SELECTION_CAN_1) && 1 ) {return TRUE;}
```

Does this extra logical AND actually change anything about the code, or is it just superfluous?  I tried searching for this online, but the closest I found to an answer is [Short-Circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) which doesn't seem to apply in these situations because short-circuiting a 1 is useless.

In short, what does Logical AND 1 do for variable declaration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be a trick to force any non-zero number to `1`, while keeping zeros - alongside a more common [`!!(expr)` idiomatic construct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10307281/335858).

The idea is to set `LED_GRN` to `1` or `0` based on the value of `ivLEDGrnSequence & ivLEDSlot`.

Other ways to do the same thing are as follows:

```
LED_GRN = !!(ivLEDGrnSequence & ivLEDSlot);
LED_GRN = (ivLEDGrnSequence & ivLEDSlot) != 0;
```

Comment: That makes more sense.  Thanks for the alternatives to that approach!
edit:  Is there any use for it in the conditional, as above?

Comment: Another way: `LED_GRN = (ivLEDGrnSequence & ivLEDSlot) ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: Or simply: `bool LED_GRN = ivLEDGrnSequence & ivLEDSlot`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It should work on modern compilers (certainly when conforming to C11). `bool` or more specifically `_Bool` was a late addition to the language. So out-of-date compilers may display quirky behavior when dealing with `bool`.

Answer (score 4):

Doing `x && 1` produces either 1 or 0, regardless of what non-zero value the left operand evaluates to.

From the C standard:

> **§6.5.13 Logical AND operator**
>
> The && operator shall yield 1 if both of its operands compare unequal
>   to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

Answer (score 3):

It's converting the result of the bitwise AND to either 0 or 1. The result of the bitwise AND can be 0 or any non-zero number. But after the logical AND, the result can only be 0 or 1.

So the first two examples may be useful. The third example with the `if` statement is definitely not useful, since `if` converts the expression to a boolean.

Answer (score 3):

The result of logical operation (in this  case `&&`) is either `0` or `1`. The result of arithmetic or bitwise operation (`&` in this case) is `0` or non-`0`. If we want to convert any non-`0` to `1` we perform a logical operation on it. The more common and idiomatic way to accomplish this is the double negation:

```
LED_GRN = !!(ivLEDGrnSequence & ivLEDSlot);
```