# What does !! (bang bang) mean?

Tags: c, logical-operators, negation

Can't find a reference to this anywhere -- I have the following code I'm trying to work with and can *anyone* please tell me what the !! means in this context? Just to be clear it's "bang bang" !! not "pipe pipe" ||. Thanks in advance!

```
/* Branch prediction */
#ifdef __GNUC__
# define likely(p)     __builtin_expect(!!(p), 1)
# define unlikely(p)   __builtin_expect(!!(p), 0)
# define unreachable() __builtin_unreachable()
#else
# define likely(p)     (!!(p))
# define unlikely(p)   (!!(p))
# define unreachable() ((void)0)
#endif
```

Comment: `!!(expression)` turns expression (assuming non-void) into `0` or `1`: `!!3.14159 ==> 1`; `!!sqrt(0) ==> 0`; `!!true ==> 1`; `!!false ==> 0`

Comment: Ask  yourself what would `!(!(p))` mean - same thing.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10307447/2410359)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "!!" in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751973/what-is-in-c)

Comment: THANK YOU so much -- apologies for the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `!` operator performs the *logical NOT* operation.  If it's operand is 0 the result is 1, and if the operand is non-zero the result is 0.

So `!!` is the logical NOT operator applied twice.  So what does this do?  If the operand is 0, the inner `!` converts it to 1, then the outer `!` converts that to 0.  If the operand is non-zero, the inner `!` converts it to 0, then the outer `!` converts that to 1.

So `!!` converts a value to its boolean equivalent.  If the value is 0, it remains 0, otherwise it becomes 1.

Answer (score 0):

`!` is a simple boolean "Not" operation.

You're probably familiar with it as in:

```
if (!x)  // If x is 0, then execute the if-statement.
```

`!!` is two of those chained together, which has the effect of taking *any* non-zero value and converting it to `1`/`true`, and any zero value stays `zero`/`false`

---

It is used in certain macros where a 1-or-0 value is needed, or when you want to convert an arbitrary value (pointer, double, char, etc) to a pure 1-or-0 boolean value.

Comment: "any zero value stays zero/false" --> true, yet its type may change.  E.g. `!!(-0.0)` becomes `(int) 0`.

Comment: THANK you to everyone who responded -- many thanks!