# What does return !!myVar mean?

Tags: c, unary-operator, negation

I'm reading an open code in C which uses glib, and I found something like this

```
gboolean function()
{
  guint myVar = 0;
  myVar = (!!globalVar1 + !!globalVar2 + !!globalVar3);
  return !!myVar;
}
```

I don't understand what's exactly happening with that double exclamation mark.

Comment: `!` is a logical `not`. `!!` is logical `not` applied twice. This is effectively converting any non-zero value into `1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does !! (bang bang) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61274027/what-does-bang-bang-mean)

Comment: [What is "!!" in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14751973/995714), [!! c operator, is a two NOT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10307281/995714)

Comment: What is `gboolean function()`?  Even in the 80s it would have been considered bad practice to name a function "function".  But it's not the 80s, and you should declare the parameters.

Comment: I've always called this "Boolean reduction"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's at first consider this statement

```
myVar = (!!globalVar1 + !!globalVar2 + !!globalVar3);
```

Now according to the C Standard (6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators)

> 5 The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of
> its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand
> compares equal to 0. The result has type int. The expression !E is
> equivalent to (0==E)

For example
If you have a variable like this

```
int x = 10;
```

then applying the operator `!` to the variable `!x` you will get 0. Applying the operator the second time `!!x` you will get 1. It is the same if to write `x != 0`.

So the result of the assignment is a non-zero value if at least one of the operands, `globalVar1`, `globalVar2`, and `globalVar3`. is not equal to 0.

The above statement can be rewritten the following way

```
myVar = ( ( globalVar1 != 0 ) + ( globalVar2 != 0 ) + ( globalVar3 != 0 ) );
```

The result of the assignment can be either 0 (if all operands are equal to 0), or 1 (if only one operand is not equal to 0), or 2 ( if two operands equal to 0), or 3 (if all operands are equal to 0).

The function need to return 1 if at least one operand is not equal to 0 or 1 otherwise.

You could just write in the return statement

```
return myVar != 0;
```

But the author of the code decided to write

```
return !!myVar;
```

It seems he likes very much the negation operator `!`.:)

The purpose of this "balancing act" with the negation operator is to return exactly either 0 or 1.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks. It was a typo.:)

Answer (score 4):

The unary `!` operator performs a logical NOT operation.  If its operand is non-zero, it evaluates to 0.  If its operand is 0, it evaluates to 1.

When two of them are put together like this, it normalizes the operand to a boolean value.  So if the operand is 0 the result is 0 and if the operand is non-zero the result is 1.

In the context of the larger expression:

```
myVar  = (!!globalVar1 + !!globalVar2 + !!globalVar3);
```

This will set `myVar` to a value between 0 and 3.  Then this:

```
return !!myVar;
```

Normalizes that value to 0 or 1.  So the end result is that 1 is returned if any of the 3 variables are non-zero, otherwise 0 is returned.

The body of the function can be rewritten as:

```
return globalVar1 || globalVar2  || globalVar3;
```

Which more clearly expresses the intent.  The `||` operator does involve branching however, so the code as written was probably trying to avoid that branching.

Generally though, compilers are pretty good at optimizing, so such micro-optimizations are not really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`!!val` gives `0` if `val` is zero or `1` if `val` is not zero.

Example usage:

```
//function counting non zero elelemnts of array
size_t countNonZero(const int *array, size_t size)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    while(size--)
        count += !!*array++;
    return count;
}
```

In your example, there is no need of the `!!` operator as in C any non zero value is considered as the `true`. Simple `||` operator should be used.

that function should be rewritten as

```
gboolean function()
{
  return globalVar1 || globalVar2 || globalVar3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as the single exclamation mark, twice. It's negating a value twice.

This has the effect of turning all integers to either `0` (if they were already `0`) or `1` (if they were any non-zero value)